# Secondary electrons in X rays excites more than ionize. Why?

Tags: x-rays

In secondary electrons, it is said that electrons excite 8 times more than ionize. Only 3 eV is needed to excite and 10eV to ionize. Why is it so, as binding energy of inner shell can reach up to 70KeV. Thank you.